# Get back return value for of loop generator JS

Tags: javascript, generator

I have the following test code:

```
function *someSequence () {
    yield new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
    const result = yield testFunc() // expecting "some string" here
    yield console.log(result)
}

async function testFunc() {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000))
    return "some string" 
}
```

I need to store `testFunc` return to the `result` const as soon as it will be resolved, and then use this result in the next yield.

But if I use `for of` syntax with `return` - generator will exit on the first yield.

```
for await (const item of someSequence) {
    return item
}
```

How do I return to yield with `for` loop? (for every yield in the sequence)

```
// I don't know how many yields are in the sequence.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to write to a const, but here is how I'd do it:

```
async function testFunc() {
  const data = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve("string"), 5000))
}
```

Depending on what you want to do, you can make this more readable:

```
async function testFunc() {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
  return "something";
}
```

**Edit:** Still not 100% sure I understand what you are looking for but hopefully this helps:

```
async function *someSequence () {
  await waitSeconds(1);
  yield "a";
  yield testFunc();
}

async function testFunc() {
  await waitSeconds(1);
  return "some string" 
}

async function waitSeconds(count) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, count*1000));
}

async function main() {
  const iterator = someSequence();
  for await (const item of iterator) console.log(item);
}

main()
```

Comment: The question is `how return to yield?`, I don't know how your contribution is helping to answer it, but I appreciate your styling input

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming your question was broader than necessary and I focused on the wrong part. I'll edit my answer to be (hopefully) more useful

Comment: Yes, this is exactly my point, I can do this with no problem at all. But if I need to return something back to the generator (by storing the result in a const) `const result = yield testFunc()` and reed it from it's next yield then I have a problem to solve. To be clear, in your answer you read from `console.log` inside `for of` loop, but I need to be able to reed the result from inside the generator itself

Comment: Couldn't you do `const result = await testFunc()` and then `yield result` ?

Comment: Yes, it is great suggestion, but it's lacking yield's flexibility to call em in exact time. Thank you anyway (`testFunc` will be executed immediately after the preceding yield, what if I want to execute it later in time?)